# No response to question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I recently asked a question which did not receive any attention at all (no comments or answers, just a like). What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers):

> ## What should I do if no one answers my question?
>
> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on any question more than two days old.

Comment: Maybe this is not the right place to rant. But I understand OP's frustration. I have the feeling that this Physics Stackexchange community has lost tolerance for basic questions and it seems most members do not make an effort in trying to understand and address OP's question. Instead. This behaviour makes feel that many users tend to be arrogant and have an urge of showing their intellectual superiority and knowledge of Physics. I don't want to simply rant and try to make anyone angry by writing this. I just would like that most users would be nicer and more helpful

Comment: @cinico and if one provides answers that are not of sufficient minimum length and don't contain at least one pdf, they get downvoted, usually without comment, even when one tries to eplain something in simple terms...